# Xamarin PCL C# - Deserialize string to a JSONObject/JSONArray

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, portable-class-library

I've worked a lot with Android but today I have to work with Xamarin.
I'm making a PCL class and I'm trying to create a JSON object from a string (`HttpWebResponse` converted into a string) for calling from an Android wrapper.

After some research I wasn't able to find anything which really answers my question.

Ultimately I want be able to just call something like this:

```
string value = jsonObject.get("key").getAsString();
```

I get a string from http response and then I want to convert it into a JSON object. When the JSON object is created, I want to extract a value like in the example. However, I'm making it in a PCL, so is it possible to do this in Xamarin/C# from a PCL?

Thank for the help and reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deserialize the string into an object using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library:

`Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(jsonFromServer);`

You can also use `HttpClient` class instead of `HttpWebRequest` and automatically deserialize response into your object:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("/accounts");

Account account = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Account>();
```

If you server returns different StatusCode when error happens you can use `HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode` to decide which type to deserialize the response into. If not you can use `var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonText);` and access the properties like this: `jsonObject["someKey"]`

You'll need [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/) library from Nuget

Comment: Thank for this fast answer ! I already saw that I can make it like you did, so maybe I didn't understand something. We are ok that I can, sometime, get an error response and then, it's not the same object as Account (if I take your code as example). So it can be either an Account object like or an Error object like? Do you understand what I mean?